# Сравнение значений в массивах и возврат с помощью 1,0,-1

Tags: javascript, массивы, compare

Не могу понять из теоретического курса, как сравниваются значения и что при этом возвращается ?

```
    function compare(a, b) {
      if (a > b) return 1; // если первое значение больше второго
      if (a == b) return 0; // если равны
      if (a < b) return -1; // если первое значение меньше второго
    }
    
    let arr = [ 1, 2, 15 ];
    arr.sort(compareNumeric);
    console.log(arr);  // 1, 2, 15
```

// если 1>2, то возвращаем 1
// далее сравниваем 2<15, возвращаем -1. что такое -1 ? предыдущее какое-то значение ?

Comment: Чтобы отсортировать массив, функции `sort` необходимо уметь сравнивать элементы массива между собой. Для этого она использует компаратор `compare`. Пусть `a` и `b` два элемента из массива `arr`, и `sort` хочет понять в каком порядке относительно друг друга они должны следовать в сортированном массиве. Для этого она вызывает компаратор. `let order = comp(a, b);`. Если `order < 0`, то `sort` считает, что `a` должен предшествовать `b` в сортированном массиве. Если `order > 0`, то `sort` считает, что `b` должен предшествовать `a`. Если `order === 0`, то `sort` считает, что `a` и `b` равны.

Comment: `если 1>2, то возвращаем 1 // далее сравниваем 2<15`. Совсем не обязательно, что функция `sort` сравнивает элементы массива именно в таком порядке. Порядок сравнения задаётся используемым [алгоритмом сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8). Какой именно алгоритм используется решают разработчики функции `sort`. Но именно ваш компаратор определяет порядок следования элементов в сортированном массиве.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фактически это знак разности между сравниваемыми a и b. Для равных чисел будет 0, и т.д. Такой вариант лучше, так как позволяет гарантированно избежать целочисленного переполнения в случае обычного вычисления разности a - b.

Answer (score 0):

> что такое -1? предыдущее какое-то значение ?

компараторы обычно используются не оторвано от чего-либо, а **в чём-то**. Самое понятное - это использование в сортировке. Сортировка должна работать по какому-то алгоритму. Для функции сортировки нужно сообщить, по какому принципу она должна различать между собой значения. Она не знает что "Иван" должен идти после "Аня", или что "124" должно идти после "120". Этой функции надо это подсказать.  Поэтому у неё есть некая своя логика и договорённость с программистами: пожалуйста, если значение `a` нужно поставить правее `b`, то дай мне значение такое-то, а если наоборот - то вот такое.. Программисту она говорит, что "мне нужны такие-то значения для понимания что идёт за чем".  А сама функция при этом внутри себя в своей логике, для сортировки, использует эти 1, 0, -1 для сравнения, если утрированно, то она внутри просто использует `if` и если условие равно какому-то значению, то логика идёт по какой-то ветке. Например если копаратор вернул -1, то функция делает так

```
if (результатФункции равен - 1) { 
    делаю какую-то большую сравнительную непосильную логику,
    которая не видна из вне
}

if (результатФункции равен 1) { 
    делаю другую какую-то логику
}

if (результатФункции равен 0) { 
    делаю так и сяк
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь стало понятней

Comment: @user533420 если ответ помог - галочку слева от ответа тык!))